# Drop down menu isn't working with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a drop-down menu with these codes. But unfortunately, this isn't working for me. If I click on the drop-down menu it doesn't open sub-menus.

How can I fix this?

```
<div id="control-panel" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 row">
    <div id="time-dropdown" class="dropdown col-xs-3">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Any Time
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Any Time</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Past Week</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Past Month</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Past Year</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="num-results-dropdown" class="dropdown col-xs-3">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        10 Results
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">10 Results</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">20 Results</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">30 Results</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="tld-dropdown" class="dropdown col-xs-3">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Any TLD
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Any TLD</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">.edu</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">.gov</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Sir, if I click on the drop-down menu it doesn't open sub-menus.

Comment: You use bootstrap? If not, you can show your css and js files?

Comment: You should include more details

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap version 3 & 4 the above code works fine without any changes.

In order to make it work with Bootstrap version 5, you need to change the **data-toggle** command to **data-bs-toggle**, then it will work as expected.

```
data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
```

Here is the modified code for Bootstrap version 5:

```
<div id="control-panel" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 row">
  <div id="time-dropdown" class="dropdown col-xs-3">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      Any Time
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Any Time</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Past Week</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Past Month</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Past Year</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="num-results-dropdown" class="dropdown col-xs-3">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      10 Results
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">10 Results</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">20 Results</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">30 Results</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="tld-dropdown" class="dropdown col-xs-3">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      Any TLD
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Any TLD</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">.edu</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">.gov</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```